# SELECT avg(unit_cost) FROM my_table WHERE running total sum(quantity) < '$someNumber'

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Using PHP to interact with SQL database

sql table relavant columns:
id | product_ID | quantity | unit_cost

**What I am trying to accomplish:**
As I enter in new lines, occasionally the boss will want to know for example the *average  unit cost for the last 10,000 units*.

How do i write something that will acheive that? something like:

```
SELECT AVG(unit_cost) FROM records_receiving WHERE CUMULATIVE_SUM(QUANTITY)< '10000';
```

Everything I have tried ends up either a result from one row that has a quantity less than 10,000, or ends up averaging all rows, Or gets nothing at all.

I tried:

```
SELECT id, total_cost, manual_adjustment, quantity 
FROM records_receiving 
WHERE product = '".$gotTheMaterials['ID']."' 
ORDER BY ID DESC limit 50;
```

and

```
SELECT m.id, AVG(m.unit_cost) AS costAvg
FROM   records_receiving m
JOIN   records_receiving m1 ON m1.id <= m.id
WHERE  m.quantity < '".$gotTheMaterials['quantity']."'
AND m.product = '".$gotTheMaterials['ID']."'
GROUP  BY m.id
HAVING SUM(m1.quantity) < '".$gotTheMaterials['quantity']."'
ORDER  BY ID DESC
LIMIT  1"
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: First  i would answer to your question SELECT AVG(unit_cost) FROM records_reForst i ceiving WHERE CUMULATIVE_SUM(QUANTITY)< '10000' Group by product_ID; but withouit any data it is a speculation especially seeing your select query

Comment: ```SELECT AVG(unit_cost) FROM `records_receiving` WHERE product='5' AND SUM(quantity) < '100' Group by product;``` This gives the following error:#1111 - Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this in 2 steps.

First write a query that calculates the running total of units. Then use this as a subquery in a query that filters it down to the running total up to 10,000, and calculates the average cost.

```
SELECT AVG(unit_cost)
FROM (<subquery>) AS x
WHERE total_quantity <= 10000
```

So now we have to figure out how to write the subquery that calculates a running total of units sold, so you can filter it down to the last 10,000 units.

In MySQL 8.0 you can do this with window functions, but I haven't learned how to use those yet. Pre-8.0 you need to use a session variable to calculate a running total.

```
SELECT unit_cost, @total := @total + quantity AS total_quantity
FROM (
    SELECT unit_cost, quantity
    FROM records_receiving
    ORDER BY id DESC
) AS t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @total := 0) AS vars
```

Put this all together, you get:

```
SELECT AVG(unit_cost) as avg_cost
FROM (
    SELECT unit_cost, @total := @total + quantity AS total_quantity
    FROM (
        SELECT unit_cost, quantity
        FROM records_receiving
        ORDER BY id DESC
    ) AS t
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @total := 0) AS vars
) AS x
WHERE total_quantity <= 10000
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ceNrtaoEvr3Zug7Dr5Gqx8/0)

Comment: This still averages all the rows that have quantitys below 10,000, as opposed to going backwards and stopping once the sum total of 10,000 has been hit. For example if I had 4 rows with quantitiy of 4000, and different unit costs, It should go from the last one entered and find 4000, then go to the next record and add the 4000 to the 4000 on that row and see if 8000<10000. It is so then it gets the next record 12000<10000  it is NOT, so then it would stop and average the unit cost fields for those records

Comment: The problem is that MySQL optimizes HAVING strangely in this case. I changed it to a `WHERE` outside the subquery, I think it works now.

Comment: Ah, yep that was it! I added `WHERE product='$productNumber'` in the inner FROM  to get the avg for only that product. Thanks so much Barmar!